# How do I login through HTTP Post

Tags: android, http-post

I am trying to make a Auto Login Application on Android.
I am facing a problem that I can't login the website by my http post method.
This is the snippet of the website.
How to I make a correct post to login?
Now, in my code, I only have use two parameters which are login[username] and login[password]

```
 <form method="POST">
        <dl>
            <dt>安全連線</dt>
            <dd>
                <label for="security">
                    <input id="security" type="checkbox" />使用安全連線
                </label>
            </dd>
        </dl>
    <dl>
    <dt>登入類型</dt>
    <dd>
        <select name="login[type]">
        <option value="0">資工系帳號</option>
        <option value="1">計中帳號</option>
        <option value="2">校際無線漫遊</option>
        </select>
    </dd>
    </dl>
        <dl>
    <dt>登入帳號</dt>
    <dd>
        <input id="username" name="login[username]" type="text" />
    </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
    <dt>登入密碼</dt>
    <dd>
        <input id="password" name="login[password]" type="password" />
    </dd>
    </dl>
    <div id="buttons">
    <button id="submit" type="submit">登 入</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can use CURL for the same.

Comment: Then you forgot login[type] and maybe submit and security